# How to run zxing apps on avd

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I m new to android

i have installed BarcodeScanner3.72.apk on MY AVD for testing if it works or not

My AVD Camera is working properly i can get image with it.

But whenever i start Barcode Scanner app it shows black and white background

I am not getting whats the problem.

One more thing i have also install same app on My Samsung Galaxy but it can't read barcode.

is there anything that i should keep in mind to use barcode app on samsung Galaxy!!

Sorry for my english !!!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no camera preview available in the AVD, so the black and white pattern you see is normal, and just the AVD's fake video stream.

Tom Gibara has [posted the famous and canonical way to slip a live video feed into code](http://www.tomgibara.com/android/camera-source) that's running on the AVD. YOu would need to modify the Barcode Scanner source for this to work.

Barcode Scanner works well on the Samsung Galaxy, I'm not sure what issue you're having.